# Adding url link to html marquee

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding and trying to figure out how to add a link to my marquee. I would also like for there to be no colour change or underline animation. Any suggestions?

```css
.Marquee {
  color: #da6fe2;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: work sans;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<marquee class="Marquee" direction="right" scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll">HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO</marquee>
```

I tried to add but for some reason it overwrites the style when I do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The marquee tag is deprecated see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is, You can put `marquee` tag inside `<a>` tag.

```css
.Marquee {
  color: #da6fe2;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: work sans;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href = "https://stackoverflow.com"><marquee class="Marquee" direction="right" scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll">HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO</marquee></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding something like this :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
   onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" 
   onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()">HELLO</a>
</marquee>
```

And to make the link not overwrites the style you can add this to style :

```
.Marquee a {
       text-decoration:none;
       color: #da6fe2;
 }
```

```css
.Marquee {
  color: #da6fe2;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: work sans;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Marquee a {
   text-decoration:none;
   color: #da6fe2;
}

.Marquee a:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<marquee class="Marquee" direction="right" scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll">HELLO 
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
   onmouseover="this.parentNode.stop()" 
   onmouseout="this.parentNode.start()">
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; HELLO

</a>
</marquee>
```

Comment: This way the text will stop moving on hover.

Comment: This is all worked! Thank you. What about adding colour change to text on hover?

Comment: You can add it using the `:hover` selector, check my update